# ASP.net MVC 5 Razor dropdown box

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Hey all I am new to Razor MVC and wanted to make a select box that has the past 10 years listed inside it (2016, 2015, 2014, etc....).

This is my current Controllers code:

```
public ActionResult loadPast10Years()
{
    List<int> last10Years = new List<int>();
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

    for (int i = currentYear - 10; i < currentYear; i++)
    {
        last10Years.Add(i);
    }

    ViewBag["last10Years"] = last10Years;

    return View();
}
```

And my Razor code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("last10Years", (SelectList)ViewBag["last10Years"], "--Select One--")
```

But I have an error when loading the page that says:

> InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'last10Years'.

So... What am I missing?

Comment: Side note: You can simplify the code for generating the `SelectList` to `new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it in the view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Last Ten Years", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LastTenYears, "Select A Year")
```

and in your `Action`

```
List<int> last10Years = new List<int>();
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

for (int i = currentYear - 10; i < currentYear; i++)
{
  last10Years.Add(i);
}

ViewBag.LastTenYears = new SelectList(last10Years);
```

You can see a demo **[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jFNxHn)**

Following from your comment please find below my updated answer.

I would first create a `Model` class which we will be using in our view. In this model class you can have your appropriate properties. For now we're only going to be using `SelectlistItem`

so our class will look like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LastTenYears { get; set; }
}
```

Then in our controller we can create a method which will provide us the information for our drop down.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetLastTenYears()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

    for (int i = currentYear - 10; i < currentYear; i++)
    {
       ddl.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(),  Value = i.ToString() });
    }

     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> lastTenYears = ddl;

     return lastTenYears;
}
```

Now we want to pass this data to the view. For argument sake I will use `Index` as a view but you can pass it to whatever view you like. So we will change our `Index` action to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
   viewModel.LastTenYears = GetLastTenYears(); //get the drop down list

   return View(viewModel); //we're passing our Model to the view
}
```

Finally, we want to make sure our view knows which `Model` to use so we will do the following the beging of the `Index.cshtml` file

```
@model YourNameSpace.ViewModel
```

and our `DropDownList` helper method will now change to point to the property in our `Model` class as

```
@Html.DropDownList("Last Ten Years", Model.LastTenYears, "Please select a year")
```

Comment: That worked but how would it work if I had it in its own function and not in the **public IActionResult Index()**  since my original question had it in its own function?

Comment: @StealthRT From your current code it looks like you're returning a view

Comment: so instead of returning the View I would be returning viewBag?

Comment: @StealthRT If I understand correctly you want a method where you put all the values into `SelectList` and then use that whenever required in multiple views?

Comment: I would just like to separate my code from the index function. I like having my own functions for each control on the page.

Comment: @StealthRT Ok bare with me i'll quickly knock up something

Comment: @StealthRT I've updated my answer, let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, Izzy!

Comment: This is creating a `<select>` with a name attribute that has no relationship to the a model and would not bind to anything when submitted. The view model needs a property say `int SelectedYear` and then in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, Model.LastTenYears, "Please select a year")`

Comment: @stephenmuecke I completely agree with you.. this was just a really basic example I assumed the op knows the basics of our the values are passed from the view to the controller

Answer (score 0):

There are few issue in your code right now.

- Don't name the ViewBag key same as the DropDownList name, they don't
  work well together, you can change the ViewBag Key name to something like last10YearsOptions`instead of`last10Years`, so that it is different than control name.
- You have not create `SelectList` in controller before adding to `ViewBag`, but you are casting it to `SelectList` in View.
- In `ViewBag` values are stored like `ViewBag.SomeKey= "SomeValue"`, but you are doing it wrong way.

After Fixing the above problems your code will look like :

```
ViewBag.last10YearsOptions = last10Years.Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
                                                     { 
                                                       Text = x.ToString(),
                                                       Value = x.ToString()
                                                     }
                                                );
```

and then in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("last10Years",
                   "--Select One--", 
                   ViewBag.last10YearsOptions as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
                   null )
```

Comment: So **ViewData** should be **ViewBag**?

Comment: there are two to three issues in your code, i have update the post.

Comment: Doing all of that above I get the error: **RuntimeBinderException: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.DynamicViewData'**

Comment: `ViewBag["last10yearOptions"]` is wrong, it should be `ViewBag.last10YearsOptions`

Comment: Alright, doing all above results in this error: **InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'last10Years'.**

Comment: in View change the DropDownList line to be :`@Html.DropDownList("last10Years","--Select One--", ViewBag.last10YearsOptions as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,null )` , wrong overload was being used before

Comment: Errors on **"--Select One--"** saying: **Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>**. And error on **ViewBag.last10YearsOptions as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,** saying: **Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>**

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` is not a dictionary with key value pairs.
also DropDownList works with ICollection ithink
so this code works form

```
@Html.DropDownList("last10Years", new SelectList(ViewBag.last10YearsOptions), "Select one from here")
```

Comment: Produces error: **ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items**

Answer (score 0):

Controller is here;

```
public ActionResult loadPast10Years()
    {
        List<int> last10Years = new List<int>();  
        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    for (int i = currentYear - 10; i < currentYear; i++)
    {
        last10Years.Add(i);
    }
    ViewBag.last10Years = new SelectList(last10Years);                       
    return View();
}
```

And View

```
@Html.DropDownList("last10Years", "--Select One--")
```

Comment: Error: **InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'last10Years'.**

Comment: Clear browser cache and try again

Comment: Or try with different browser