# JQuery not working in PartialView inside modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a "Create" form as a modal dialog when the user clicks the create button. The Modal displays the partialview that contains the form. But when the user selects a value in the dropdownlist it should us AJAX to populate other information on the form. But the jquery call to lookupVendor information doesn't fire. I know i'm missing something, but just can't see it.. So any help would be great.

Controller

```
public ActionResult LookupVendor(int? id)
        {
            string VendorContact = "";
            string VendorPartNumber = "";
            decimal VendorPrice = 0;

            if (id != null)
            {
                var vendors = (from v in dbVendor.vendors where v.idVendor == id select v).ToList();
                var tmpnumber = (from x in dbVendor.vendorpartinformations where x.IDVendor == id && x.IDParts == id select x).ToList();

                foreach (var item in vendors)
                {
                    VendorContact = item.Contact;
                    
                }

                if (tmpnumber.Count != 0)
                {

                    foreach (var item1 in tmpnumber)
                    {
                        VendorPartNumber = item1.VendorPartNumber;
                        VendorPrice = (decimal)item1.VentorPrice;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    VendorPartNumber = "Not available from this Vendor";
                }
            }


            return Json(new { VendorContact = VendorContact, VendorPartNumber = VendorPartNumber, VendorPrice = VendorPrice }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        
        public ActionResult Create(int? id, int? idVendor, int? idReference, int? Required,  RequisitionOrder model)
        {
            foreach (var Vendor in dbVendor.vendors)
            {
                model.VendorNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Vendor.Name, Value = Vendor.idVendor.ToString() });
            }

            var Tmpdetails = dbParts.parts.Where(x => x.idParts == id).ToList();

            foreach(var item2 in Tmpdetails)
            {
                model.PartNumber = item2.PartNumber;
                model.PartDescription = item2.PartDescription;
                model.StockQTY = (int)item2.PartQTY;
                if(Required != null)
                {
                    model.RequisitionQTY = (int)Required;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.RequisitionQTY = (int)model.RequisitionQTY;
                }

                foreach(var item3 in dbPartType.parttypes)
                {
                    if(item3.idPartType == item2.PartType)
                    {
                        model.PartType = item3.PartType1;
                    }
                }
            }

            
            return PartialView("Create", model);
        }
```

Main Form

```
@model MYSQL___Parts_Management.Models.ItemsToOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ItemsToOrder";
}

<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 0px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        /*font-size: 12px;*/
    }

        table.center {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

    table {
        border-spacing: 15px;
    }

    .foo {
        color: red;
    }

    .modal-dialog {
        position: relative;
        display: table; /* <-- This makes the trick */
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 300px;
    }
</style>
<br />
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("ItemToOrder", "PartRequisitions", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table style="filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity: 0.95;border:2px black solid;width:100%" ;table-layout:fixed;>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="9" bgcolor="#dddddd" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" style="font-size: 15px;border:1px black solid;padding-left:0.8ex">Parts Order</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;padding-left:2.0ex" nowrap>Part Description</th>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;padding-left:2.0ex" nowrap>Part Number</th>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;padding-left:2.0ex" nowrap>Minimum QTY</th>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;padding-left:2.0ex" nowrap>Maximum QTY</th>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;padding-left:2.0ex" nowrap>Stocked QTY</th>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;padding-left:2.0ex" nowrap>Requested QTY</th>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;padding-left:2.0ex" nowrap>Required QTY</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Results.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Results)
        {

            <tr style="font-size:12px; font-weight: bold">
                @if (item.QTYDifference != 0)
                {
                    <td width="230" nowrap>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartDescription) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.idParts)
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartMinQTY)
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartMaxQTY)
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartQTY)
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestedQTY)
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QTYDifference)
                    </td>
                    <td> @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "PartRequisitions", new { @id = item.idParts, @Required = item.QTYDifference }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt", @title = "Create PO", @data_modal = "" })</td>
                    <td></td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    }
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9"></td>
    </tr>

</table>



}


<div id='myModal' class='modal fade'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/appjs/PRequisitionIndex.js")

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
}
```

Main Form - Script file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
        
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });


});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {

        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    window.location.href = "/PartRequisitions/ItemsToOrder";
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}


        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#data').after('<div id="nav"></div>');
            var rowsShown = 10;
            var rowsTotal = $('#data tbody tr').length;
            var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
            for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
                var pageNum = i + 1;
                $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
            }
            $('#data tbody tr').hide();
            $('#data tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
            $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
            $('#nav a').bind('click', function () {

                $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
                var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
                var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
                $('#data tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
                    css('display', 'table-row').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
            });
        });
```

Create Form as partial view

```
@model MYSQL___Parts_Management.Models.RequisitionOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Parts Requisition";
    Layout = "";
}

<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 0px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        /*font-size: 12px;*/
    }

        table.center {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

    table {
        border-spacing: 15px;
    }
</style>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "partrequisitions", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" } ))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.idReference)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ReferenceNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PartDescription)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PartNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.StockQTY)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PartType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.RequisitionQTY)

    <div class="modal-body">

        <table style="filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity: 0.95;border:2px black solid;width:100%" ;table-layout:fixed;>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" bgcolor="#dddddd" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" style="font-size: 15px;border:1px black solid;padding-left:0.8ex">Part Information</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Part Category:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex" nowrap>@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.PartType)</td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Part Number:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex" nowrap>@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.PartNumber)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Description:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex" nowrap>@Html.DisplayFor(C => C.PartDescription)</td>

                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Stocked QTY:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex">@Html.DisplayFor(C => C.StockQTY)</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br />
        <table style="filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity: 0.95;border:2px black solid;width:100%" ;table-layout:fixed;>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5" bgcolor="#dddddd" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" style="font-size: 15px;border:1px black solid;padding-left:0.8ex">Order Information</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Vendor:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex" nowrap>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idVendor, Model.VendorNames, "-- Select Vendor --", new { @id = "VendorName1", style = "width: 200px;", required = "required" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.idVendor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Reference Number:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex" nowrap>@*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idReference, Model.ReferenceNumbers, "-- Select Reference Number --", new { style = "width:900px", id = "ReferenceNumber1" })*@</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Contact:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex" nowrap> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.VendorContact) </td>

                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Vendor Number:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex" nowrap>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.VendorPartNumber)</td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Vendor Price: ($)</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex">@Html.TextBoxFor(C => C.VendorPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @oncut = "return false", @oncopy = "return false", @onpaste = "return false", @type = "number", @min = "0", @max = "999", @id = "VendorPrice" }, style = "width:50px;" })</td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Confirmed Price:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.ConfirmedPrice, 0) No @Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.ConfirmedPrice, 1) Yes
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 14px;padding-left:3.0ex;padding-top:0.8ex">Order Qty:</td>
                <td style="font-weight:normal;font-size: 14px;padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex">@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.RequisitionQTY, new { htmlAttributes = new { @oncut = "return false", @oncopy = "return false", @onpaste = "return false", @type = "number", @min = "0", @max = "999", @id = "RequisitionQTY" }, style = "width:50px;" })</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

        <table class="center">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Appjs/PRequisitionCreate.js")

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").removeData("validator");
        $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    </script>

}
```

Create Form - Script File

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});


$("#RequisitionQTY").keydown(function (evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if ((charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (!(charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105)))) && charCode != 46) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});

$("#VendorPrice").keydown(function (evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if ((charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (!(charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105)))) && charCode != 46 && charCode != 110) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});

$("#VendorName1").change(function () {
    var tempID = document.getElementById("VendorName1");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("LookupVendor", "partrequisitions")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: tempID },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#myModalContent").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MYSQL___Parts_Management.Models
{
    public class RequisitionOrder
    {
        //DropDownListFor data
        public RequisitionOrder()
        {
            this.VendorNames = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        public List<SelectListItem> VendorNames { get; set; }
        public int idVendor { get; set; }
        public int idReference { get; set; }

        //DisplayFor data
        public int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartType { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartDescription { get; set; }
        public int StockQTY { get; set; }
        public string VendorName { get; set; }
        public string VendorContact { get; set; }
        public string VendorPhone { get; set; }
        public string VendorPartNumber { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vendor Price required")]
        public decimal VendorPrice { get; set; }
        public int ConfirmedPrice { get; set; }
        public int RequisitionQTY { get; set; }
        public int ReceivedQTY { get; set; }
        public int PReceivedQTY { get; set; } /*Previously Received QTY*/
    }
}
```

Layout (Nav Bar)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                            <img src="~/upload/logo.png" style="height:auto; width:30%; margin-top:-15px"/>
                        </a>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Part Management System", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="False">Help<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            }

                            @* Rest of Nav Menu truncated because of space. *@

                        </ul>
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container body-content">
                @RenderBody()
                <hr />
                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                </footer>
            </div>

            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Does the VendorName1 dropdown change event fire? are you sure the ajax isn't making the call and coming back with an error as without capturing the error it could be being masked?

Comment: @PatrickHume, the change event doesn't appear to be firing as I have a break point set on the action it calls and it never gets tripped.

Comment: Does the rendered Html for the drop-down have the id attribute set? Also, try putting the change event hook 
"$("#VendorName1").change(function () {" 
inside the 
$(document).ready(function () {

Comment: @PatrickHume, moving the change event inside the readyfunction didn't change anything.. Had the change event update a textbox with the Dropdown ID Value, but it just shows "0" regardless of what's selected.  This shouldn't be because the dropdown list populated from the Model associated with the Partialview? The controller is assigning ID values in the model.

Comment: could you try this:

@ Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idVendor, new SelectList(Model.VendorNames, "Value", "Text"), new { @ id = "VendorName1", style = "width: 200px;", required = "required"  })

you could also add 

new { @ id = "VendorName1" , @ onchange="callChangefunc(this.value)"... 

to the new { brackets and call the js function that way

can't test it so may  need a tweak, but not the added  new SelectList syntax, are you able to post the rendered html (not the razor code but what gets rendered to the page)

Comment: @PatrickHume tried your suggestions and still same results.. Unable to add a screen capture. The site isn't allowing. This might be a strange question, what script file should the change event function be in? The main form or the partialview?

Comment: im surprised that add new { @ id = "VendorName1" , @ onchange="callChangefunc(this.value)"... to the new { doesn't work as that basic vanilla JS ? it shouldn't really matter as razor will render everything as one page, its hard to help without a working example, see if these help you and check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224512/asp-net-mvc-5-razor-dropdown-box and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/ see if they help

Comment: @PatrickHume here's something strange.. I created the scripts and controller and create view, everything worked. Loaded the create form as a modal and everything worked. But I forgot to remove the layout (nav bar) from the form, so that appeared in the modal. As soon as it was removed, the scripts file no longer function.. Hmm...

Comment: if its the shared _Layout.cshtml in MVC that has the following :    
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
removing it means the js library scripts you need won't be there and is probably why it stopped working try re-adding them on the shared _ViewImports.cshtml or _ViewStart.cshtml

Comment: @PatrickHume thank you for all your help.. Everything appears to be operational.

Comment: fantastic! out of interest what was fix ?

Comment: @PatrickHume I ended up making a stripped down "blank" layout file that just had the Stype.Render and Script.Render as well as the RenderBody and added it to the create form and everything was operational. I know that's a shortcut...

Comment: kewl glad you sorted it sorry i couldn't do more to help you

Comment: @PatrickHume you did in a way and Thank you!!!

Comment: kewl-e-o glad to know that thank you for saying so =)

Answer (score 0):

By excluding the _layout file from the partial view, the script file was not firing as expected. After a lengthy conversation with Patrick Hume, I Created a _blank layout file (as below) and everything was working as expected. It's probably not the cleanest way to do this. But it worked.

_blank layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>
   
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```